# Express Router() and Passport Authenticate()

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I am playing around with Express(v4.15), Passport(v0.4.0), and Passport-JWT(v3.0.1).  I am using Node version 8.9.0.

I can't seem to get Express.Router()s and my passport.authenticate() call to work properly.  What am I doing wrong here?

./routes/user.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/user', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Secured Page: user account settings');
});

module.exports = router;
```

./app.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var passport = require('passport');
var passportJWT = require('passport-jwt');
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var Strategy = passportJWT.Strategy;
var ExtractJWT = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;

var userDB = require('./userdb');
var config = require('./config/config');
var params = {
  secretOrKeyProvider: function (req, rawJWT, done) { done(null, config.jwtSecret); },
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
};

var user = require('./routes/user');

// ...

var strategy = new Strategy(params, function jwtVerify (payload, done) {
  console.log('payload recieved', payload);
  // usually this would be a database call
  var user = userDB[_.findIndex(userDB, {id: payload.id})];
  if (user) {
    done(null, user);
  } else {
    done(new Error('User not found'), false);
  }
});

passport.use(strategy);

//...

app.use('/user', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), user);
```

This is what I get in Postman:
[image: 404 Error In Postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue.

```
router.get('/user', function (req, res) {
```

It should have been:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
```

It was causing the final route to be '/user/user'